# Auto complete HTML attribute from CSS Intellij

Tags: html, css, intellij-idea

**link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet"**

**link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"**

How can I have the auto-complete for the CSS class when I applying the class in the HTML?

**div class="bar bar-header bar-positive"**

how to get auto suggestions for attributes (ex: - bar-header after writing **bar** I pressed for auto suggestion but not get the option like bar-header or bar-footer,but they are present in library css ),every other thing is working fine.

Comment: This is not a programming question but an IDE configuration issue, right?

Comment: Yes Alvaro Montoro, you are correct but if you any solution please let me know it will be great help because I am new to this language and it will help me to learn the things faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found webstrom but it is paid version :,(